# Ionic / Angular Reverse scroll input

Tags: angularjs, scroll, ionic-framework, reverse

I have a chat page in a ionic project and like most chat apps I want to start the list of messages at the bottom of the page.

As far as I know with the help of google in the web world it is not possible to generate a list of items in a reversed order on the screen like in native apps.

The most common work around for this is scroll the page to the bottom on page load. I tried this and in most cases there are performance issues, scroll delays, list not responding for a few seconds etc. so not the desired solution.

No I came up with a different approach, with css I flipped the list of items so that the list is upside down. I also flipped the items in the list so that they are flipped back and are not upside down anymore. Now I have the result I want, I have a list with items with item 1 at the bottom without the need to scroll to the bottom.

```
.listUpsideDown {
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
.messageUpsideDown {
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

There is only one downside, because I flip the list the scroll direction is also reversed. So now I'm looking for a way to reverse the scroll input direction.

I hope someone can help me with this.

I have a working fiddle with my current situation where I need to reverse the mouse scroll input direction [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/a31vdgwq/3/) .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing other workarounds, stick to scrolling to bottom. As you are using ionic, use [$ionicScrollDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/) service, Just call `$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom();` from your controller when you want to scroll to bottom.

Plus if you want to put animation, while it is going to bottom use `$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom([true])`

Comment: I already did what you suggest, but like I mention this is not working for me do to the bad performance, not smooth scrolling, and bad list response after scrolled to the bottom. So I consider that as a not working workaround.